# Measuring the intensity of raster pixels within buffers

Tags: qgis, raster, buffer, pixel, flood

I need to create a variable ranging between `0` and `1` to compute the intensity of a flood.

I have the raster file for the flood and the layer with the coordinates of the households that have been affected by the flood. I created for each coordinate a buffer with a radius of 5 km. I now need to compute the intensity of the flood in each buffer (i.e., take the number of pixels that are within each buffer and somehow compute its intensity).

I tried with a shapefile of the flood using the "Intersection" command between the buffer and the layer of the flood, but it is not an appropriate measure because I do not have information on the intensity, which is instead given by the pixels of the raster.

Any idea of how to do it?

Comment: You want to use the pixel values, or just pixel yes/no?

Comment: The pixel values - I have buffers with less intense flood and buffers with more intense flood

Comment: Try something with zonal statistics then field calculator

Comment: Yes I am trying to multiply the following (as suggested before): round(_count*pixel size/$area*100), but pixel size is too small, so the values are all 0 or "NULL"

Comment: What field type are you using for the new field?

Comment: Sorry wha do you mean?

Comment: In field calculator `Output field type` should be `Decimal` or similar, not integer,text/string etc.

Comment: Ah yes, decimal! I changed the CRS and the size of the pixels is now ok. I first clipped the buffers and the raster, then calculated the zonal statistics for the clipped area. The idea is to multiply the "count" variable with the pixel area, and the divide it with the buffer area, but results are too high (the enumerator gets too big)

Comment: Nice! Yes you will have to normalize the values to 0-1